# Need help writing conditional regex

Tags: c#, regex, string

I got a string that represents a phone number.

The format is: [phone number] - [type{1-3}] [- | " "] [name of customer]

The phone number is mandatory, but the type and name are not.

The type must start with a "-", is 1-3 characters long and ends with "-" or " "  (space) or nothing (end of string)

I've tried this regex:

```
        var phonrType = "-([A-Za-z]{1,3})(-?|\\s)";
        Match m = Regex.Match(str, phonrType);
```

but I can't figure out how to handle string with phone type only without a name:

```
"03 7963324A-FAX"    --> the regex fails for this input
```

I don't know how to say that after the type there can be "-", or " ", or nothing (and anything else is not a valid phone type).

Here are some more input strings for clarification:

```
"03 7963324-BOB/BOB" --> no phone type

"03 7963324-MOB-BOB/BOB" --> phone type is: "MOB"

"03 7963324A-FAX" -->phone type is "FAX"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a regex pattern with lookbehinds and lookaheads to match only what I want without capturing additional groups.

`(?<=\-)[A-Za-z]{1,3}(?=\-|$)`

Here are the testing results:

```
"03 7963324-BOB/BOB" --> no match
"03 7963324-MOB-BOB/BOB" --> the whole match is "MOB"
"03 7963324A-FAX" --> the whole match is "FAX"
```

Comment: thx. almost what i needed - fixed i to: (?<=\\-)[A-Za-z]{1,3}(?=\\-|\\s|$) to support also a space after the phone type

Answer (score 1):

Have a try with:

```
(?:-([A-Za-z]{1,3})(?:[- ]|$))
```